# Django - Image not displayed on webpage 404 Not found

Tags: django, python-3.x

The profile page is not displaying the profile image which is uploaded using upload_to function in models.py

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'users/%s/%s' % (instance.user, filename)
```

ImageField --> `img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, db_index=True)`

url used for the user_profile is

```
url(r'^users/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/$', views.user_profile, name='profile'),
```

the html page for user_profile.html is something like this

```html
<li>
    I am The Image
    <img src="{{ image }}" alt="img">
</li>
```

the views.py ---->

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request, username):
    image = request.user.profile.img
    image = str(image)
    image = image.strip('users/%s' % username)
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'username': request.user.username,
                                                 'image': image})
```

The url showed in the server console is

> /users/rony/f4098984_Kgo0lqi.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2665

in the above block code when clicked on the jpg image link mentioned above the image is available at the mentioned link but still the image is not getting displayed in the webpage

the github issue link is provided below.
https://github.com/bikirandas/OmexOnline/issues/2

Comment: try giving `{{ image.url }}` and see

Comment: @SammyJ used the above suggestion the image is not updated still .. instead the image error icon is also not visible now.

Comment: why are you doing this? `image = image.strip('users/%s' % username)`

Comment: @SammyJ actually when i am getting the image from the models it gives me the the url value - /users/rony/f4098984_Kgo0lqi.jpg, but when this image value is passed to the html page via views.py the url gets further updated to  /users/rony/users/rony/f4098984_Kgo0lqi.jpg  to remove the redundancy i have stirp the duplicate /users/rony/ at the views.py

Comment: So the `request.user.profile.img` gives the correct image?

Comment: yes .. it do generate the correct url ... but the urls.py configuration update it further with url defined in urls.py

Comment: @SammyJ I was thinking if the url could be some how modified to `../users/%username/%filename`. I wana try this out but can you suggest how can i implement this.

Comment: @SammyJ your 1st suggestion has worked but with few modifications on my views and settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Solution for the above issue i posted.

Change the html code as below.

```html
<img src="{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}{{ image.url}}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

and the **views.py** as shown below

```
def user_profile(request, username):
    image = request.user.profile.img
    # image = str(image)
    # image = image.strip('users/%s' % username)
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'username': request.user.username,
                                                 'image': image})
```

add `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to **urls.py**